# importar para o mysql um arquivo em txt

Tags: mysql, script

preciso de uma ajudinha, alguém sabe como importa para o mysql um arquivo em txt de tal forma

IP: dados
city: dados
state: dados
Latitude: dados
Longitude: dados
IP: dados
city: dados
state: dados
Latitude: dados
Longitude: dados

são mais de 10000 linhas desta forma

o nome é fulldata-Dia-q-foi-gerado.csv
Este arquivo é gerado em csv mas pode ser txt.
Eu preciso de um script que gere um arquivo .sql com os inserts da mysql em bash, alguém pode me ajudar?

Eu já tentei em bash com um script mas não gera com o formato certo para o insert e não está conectando ao banco mysql.

O arquivo .sql deve estar com este formato:

INSERT INTO `nometabela` (`id`, `host`, `country`, `state`, `city`, `latitude`, `longitude`) VALUES
(92,'46.105.108.104','France','None','None','488.582','23.387');

Eu tentei o script:

#!/bin/bash

## $1 = arquivo com os dados já formatados

## Será gerado um arquivo 'arquivo.SQL' com os comandos SQL

IFS=:

while read ip country city state latitude longitude;do
echo "INSERT INTO nometabela VALUES('$ip','$country','$state','$city', '$latitude', '$longitude');" >> arquivo.SQL
done < $1

Mas me retornou erro, o arquivo gerado me trás somente o campo longitude, o que pode ser?

Comment: Este link deve te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579810/how-to-import-data-from-text-file-to-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

Precisaria algumas linhas do seu arquivo txt para verificar, mas pode usar um script como:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
        ip=$(echo "$line"|cut -f 1 -d ':')
        country=$(echo "$line"|cut -f 2 -d ':')
        state=$(echo "$line"|cut -f 3 -d ':')
        city=$(echo "$line"|cut -f 4 -d ':')
        latitude=$(echo "$line"|cut -f 5 -d ':')
        longitude=$(echo "$line"|cut -f 6 -d ':')
        echo "INSERT INTO nometabela (id, host, country, state, city, latitude, longitude)  VALUES ('$ip','$country','$state','$city', '$latitude', '$longitude');" >> arquivo.SQL
done < $1
```

arquivo fonte:

```
192.168.1.1: 'france' : 'fdfsd' : '1.1.1' : '2.2.2.2'
192.168.6.1: 'xxxfrance' : 'fzzzsd' : '1.21.1' : '2.222.2.2'
192.168.1.1: 'yyyfrance' : 'fdjjjfsd' : '1.51.1' : '2.2.32.2'
```

Comment: O problema do meu arquivo é que ele é em varias linhas para o mesmo registro e depois se repetem o campos.
Exemplo:
IP: dados1
Country: dados1
State: dados1
City: dados1
Latitude:dados1
Longitude:dados1
IP:dados2
Country:dados2
State:dados2
City:dados2
Latitude:dados2
Longitude:dados2

Comment: Precisaria de algumas linhas exemplo do arquivo *e* como quer que fiquem estas linhas após convertido

Comment: IP: 103.145.12.23
Country: Netherlands
State: 
City: 
Latitude: 52.3824
Longitude: 4.8995
IP: 103.145.13.124
Country: Netherlands
State: 
City: 
Latitude: 52.3824
Longitude: 4.8995
IP: 103.145.13.192
Country: Netherlands
State: 
City: 
Latitude: 52.3824
Longitude: 4.8995

Comment: O meu arquivo esta em lista e cada campo está numa linha diferente, como eu consigo colocar os campos na mesma linha?

Comment: usa tr e sed: cat arquivo | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/IP:/\n IP:/g'
Vai conseguir organizar o arquivo em linhas. Fica mais fácil de manipular